# Error selenium + click + <rich:calendar>

Tags: selenium

I'm having trouble clicking on the element for the day in a  component. Selenium finds the element by xpath, sends the click command, however the element is not actually clicked. code and image for further understanding.

it is worth mentioning that even using JavaScriptExecutor, the click is still not possible.

```
public static void selecionarDataCalendario(By by,WebDriver driver,WebDriverWait wait, WebElement webElement) throws Throwable {
    Calendar dat = Calendar.getInstance();
    dat.setTime(new Date());
    SimpleDateFormat formatterMes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    SimpleDateFormat formatterAno = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
    SimpleDateFormat formatterDia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String mes = formatterMes.format(dat.getTime());
    String ano = formatterAno.format(dat.getTime());
    String dia = formatterDia.format(dat.getTime());

    driver.findElement(by).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='"+ dia +"']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Psi2.png)

Comment: Generally when automating web pages, most do not attempt to do things at that low of a level.  The idea is not to test the date picker itself, but to test a condition where a certain date is passed to the picker, so instead of trying to click the date itself from a drop-down, instead `.sendKeys()` the date to the web element.

Comment: Ok. Compreendo  a dica, todavia a minha ideia á imitar o comportamento de usuário na utilização do sistema. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: updating the question I noticed that the element is being found, by xpath, but it is not clickable. Already, when I look for the element by the id, it is clicked, however I can not use the location by id, since the id is generated dynamically by JSF.

Comment: updating: When I search the day of the month for the text inside the <td> tag, selenium finds 2 elements. Already when searching for the xpath, by the @id property, selenium finds only one element, which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found because I search for elements through the text. Iterate the list and click on all found elements.

```
public static void selecionarDataCalendario(By by,WebDriver driver,WebDriverWait wait, WebElement webElement) throws Throwable {
    Calendar dat = Calendar.getInstance();
    dat.setTime(new Date());
    SimpleDateFormat formatterMes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    SimpleDateFormat formatterAno = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
    SimpleDateFormat formatterDia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String mes = formatterMes.format(dat.getTime());
    String ano = formatterAno.format(dat.getTime());
    String dia = formatterDia.format(dat.getTime());

    driver.findElement(by).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    ArrayList<WebElement> elementos = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='SalvarForm:dataefeito']/tbody/tr/td[text()='"+ dia +"']"));
    for (WebElement elemento: elementos) {
        elemento.click();
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```